# Passing id variable from an anchor codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, anchor, parameter-passing

So guys you definitely know this and i am doing something wrong here, I am trying to pass the id of a username from an anchor tag like this

```
$value = '12';

echo anchor('mycontroller/'.$value.'', 'Click Here');
```

the url displays: `//myroot/mycontroller/12`

the page that supposed to load is not loading it say not found because the value 12 is recognized as a function expect something with 12 to load. My controller is loading just fine without `/12` value.

I have used also url segments but no results. I know is pretty easy but i have 2 hours struggle with it now.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I think

you have an `index()` function in your controller.

when your url is

```
//myroot/mycontroller
```

it loads

```
//myroot/mycontroller/index
```

by default,

but when your url is `//myroot/mycontroller/12`

it should give an error , because no function defined

try to change your url to

```
//myroot/mycontroller/index/12
```